# PHP SimpleXML, CodeIgniter and Apache with Suhosin

Tags: php, xml, apache, simplexml, suhosin

I have an application I am writing in PHP5, using the CodeIgniter framework.
I have it running on both Windows (using Xampp) and Ubuntu (using standard Apache, PHP, MySQL stack).

I have a form, that takes XML, parses it (using simpleXML) and posts the results into a database.

On Windows - no problem, works as intended.

On Linux - big problem. It errors out.

I have double checked the XML, and it's fine.

I removed a large amount of the XML, and it seems that it is OK.

I think it's related to the size of the XML string being posted from the form, but am not sure. Again, on Windows it's OK - on Linux, it errors out.

The size of the data posted in the form is ~160k (yeah, that's a lot of text, but it's automated - AND it's gonna eventually be about 200k).

The error is below.

Any help much appreciated.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/ci/system/application/controllers/system.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/ci/system/application/controllers/system.php(49): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 [internal function]: System->add_system() #2 /var/www/ci/system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php(233): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/ci/index.php(115): require_once('/var/www/ci/sys...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/ci/system/application/controllers/system.php on line 49

Line 49 looks like this:

`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->input->post('form_systemXML'));`

EDIT - FIXED

Found the issue. Suhosin is installed on Ubuntu. in the file /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/suhosin.ini, I enabled the line `suhosin.post.max_value_length = 65000` and changed the value to 195000. Restarted Apache, and all good. Thanks for the pointers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're running the [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) PHP extension.
Please have a look at the configuration documentation at: http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html.

The relevant option seems to be (I've never used the Suhosin extension): [suhosin.post.max_value_length](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_value_length) and/or [suhosin.request.max_value_length](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.request.max_value_length)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your PHP configuration on the Linux box and compare it to your Windows settings. Especially the following settings:

- memory_limit
- post_max_size
- magic_quotes_gpc
- max_input_time

Perhaps you can do a dump of the data posted to the script

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see what data is really coming into the server.

Comment: memory_limit: linux 16m, Windows 32m
post_max_size: linux 8m, Windows 16m
Shall change linux settings and see what happens.

Comment: Damn - updated and restarted Apache (and double checked with phpinfo() ) - no change. Same error.

Comment: Tried adding print_r($_POST), but all that came back was 

Array ( [submit] => Submit ) 

Along with the existing error message. There should be a variable for "form_systemXML". Not sure... maybe apache config ?

Comment: I cut down the XML input from 2870 lines to 990. Worked fine. Am sure it's related to size...

Answer (score 0):

You may already have tried this approach but did you check the line endings? \r\n (DOS) as opposed to \n (UNIX)? It might be that the regular expressions that simpleXML uses might be confused by them on different platforms...

Comment: SimpleXML does not care about the line endings used.
$a1="<root>\n<tag1>\r\n<tag2>\r</tag2></tag1></root>";

Comment: $x=new SimpleXmlElement($a1);
print_r($x);
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [tag1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [tag2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] =>

                )

        )

)

Comment: Nice try. The XML string _is_ generated in Windows, so I replaced all the line endings (unix2dos -u -o filename) in Ubuntu. Made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Update - found this in syslog

Nov  4 21:53:32 ubu804 suhosin[7944]: ALERT - configured request variable value length limit exceeded - dropped variable 'form_systemXML' (attacker '127.0.0.1', file '/var/www/ci/index.php')

Am looking at the apache config, now.